# how to stop vuetify v-bottom-sheet or (v-dialog) from blocking interaction with main content

Tags: vue.js, dialog, frontend, vuetify.js, bottom-sheet

We are trying to build an music playing interface on a Vue page that plays in a bottom player as described here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/bottom-sheets/#music-player

But the playlist and other controls are in the main page. But the problem is that these elements get 'blocked' or deactivated or something, there is no way to interact with them. Just like in this example.

Input elements stop working and scrolling on the main page works only by grabbing the scrollbar on the side.
@clicks are still registered, however, and scrolling on some other components work.

I think I have tried every API setting and combination in the docs, like attaching it to different dom elements, or `hide-overlay`, and `persistent`, but nothing seems to work. The same principle seems to apply to other dialogs that take focus in vuetify.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-bottom-sheet/

Does anyone have experience with this or know a workaround for it? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be best if you show us the code. Because I believe ``hide-overlay`` and ``persistent`` would do the trick. Maybe you need to check ‍‍``<v-app>`` and other main tags which has some direct impact on these sort of things.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you try accomplish this using `v-bottom-navigation`?

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour. Your best bet is `hide-overlay` in combination with  `persistent`

```html
<v-bottom-sheet
  hide-overlay
  persistent
></v-bottom-sheet>
```

Comment: Hi @tauzN, thank you for your answer. I have tried this, these are actually my settings. I will expand on it in the question. And while I understand it is intended behaviour, I still need it to do something else, preferably without building a new component myself that mimicks it.

Comment: I would recommend building your own.

Comment: I ended up doing that, using v-sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue and solve that with the "retain-focus" property

try this `<v-bottom-sheet :retain-focus="false"></v-bottom-sheet>`